# Is it Possible to create a calendar with a repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, calendar

I would like to create a calendar view of some events gets from a database,
Is it possible to make it with a repeater control? Or its the wrong way?

Txs..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET has a calendar built in that you could use. Some details are here: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_calendar.asp

I've also used the [FullCalendar jQuery plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) to achieve a similar thing.

There's no reason you couldn't use a repeater control to make the calendar, but it seems like a lot of work considering there are already controls around that could do this for you

Comment: And it's possible to add events in the calendar?

Comment: yeah. There's a whole api for it. You just need to expose a JSON endpoint